# android drawable composite images

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am trying to put together an appcompat actionbar where the back button & app icon are displayed together. What I ended up doing is make a drawable object with back arrow (<) and logo. However I was not able to position them properly.

The output should have < and logo like in the [image: image here]

Now this is the code I have is as follows but I dont know how to align them next to each other. Also, I would like the arrow to be bit smaller like the reference. How do I position both items next to each other

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:left="0dp">
                <vector
                        android:width="30dp"
                        android:height="30dp"
                        android:viewportWidth="60"
                        android:viewportHeight="60">
                        <path
                            android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:strokeWidth="6"
                            android:pathData="M30,0 L0,25 30,50"/>
                </vector>
        </item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/app_icon" android:right="50dp"  android:height="60dp" android:width="60dp" android:gravity="center" />
</layer-list>
```

Disclaimer - I am not a hardcode android programmer.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I solved it finally

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/app_icon" android:left="15dp"  android:height="40dp" android:width="40dp" android:gravity="center" />
    <item android:left="5dp" android:height="40dp" android:width="40dp" android:top="20dp">
        <vector
         android:width="50dp"
         android:height="50dp"
         android:viewportWidth="100"
         android:viewportHeight="100">
            <path
             android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:strokeWidth="6"
             android:pathData="M20,0 L10,25 20,50"/>
        </vector>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```